# Avoiding bias while dropping negative values (easy)

Tags: categorical-data, stata, categorical-encoding

Apologies for the trivial question, but I am a relative beginner.

I would like to create an index variable which sums up the responses of 7 other categorical variables which have answers ranging from 1: Always to 5: never. Hence the variable essentially measures how likely the individual is to behave in a certain way.

However my problem is, there are also answers which have 6: not applicable, -1: don't know, -9: missing, -8: inapplicable, -7: proxy respondent, -2: refused.

Obviously if I included these responses I would end up with an index variable that could have a negative value, or is wrong in some other way.

My question is: how do I appropriately exclude these variables without biasing my sample? Would a `keep if var>0 & var<6` be a standard way of doing this?

Comment: You don't know anything about bias unless data for other variables imply that observations with missing values differ systematically from the others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nick. I do not believe that to be the case, hence will go ahead and create the index variable by excluding those values.

Comment: If you have other variables then you can and should compare their values systematically compared with values of your graded variable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick's comments. But yes, in such cases, a simple and standard protocol is to drop observations with invalid answers. If you are planning to do so, you should also run tests to show that compared to the full sample, the selected observations with valid responses do not differ significantly in all observable characteristics. Although the results may still be biased due to some unobservables changed by dropping certain observations, the tests do relieve some referees' concern.

Another method I would try is to create a dummy of "invalid answer" for each categorical variable and keep all observations. When running regressions, include your index variable and all eight dummies. However, I wouldn't recommend this if only a small fraction of observations have invalid values. Just drop them.